# Java random with low percentage on boolean array (quantile function)

Tags: java, arrays, random, boolean

I have a boolean array of aproximattely 10 000 elements. I would like to with rather low,set probability (cca 0,1-0,01) change the value of the elements, while knowing the indexes of changed elements. The code that comes to mind is something like:

```
int count = 10000;
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    double x = r.nextDouble();
    if (x < rate) {
            field[i]=!field[i];
            do something with the index...
    }
}
```

However, as I do this in a greater loop (inevitably), this is slow. The only other possibility that I can come up with is using quantile function (gaussian math), however I have yet to find any free to use code or library to use. Do you have any good idea how to work around this problem, or any library (standard would be best) that could be used?

Comment: could you provide a bit more code? what's fixed and genotype?

Comment: Sorry, that was mistake. Corrected

Comment: You could simply create (0.1 * 10000) random integers, with values between 0 and 9999: These would then **exactly** be the indices that you're looking for (and toggling the booleans based on these indices would be trivial and efficient).

Comment: I don`t know whether the integers would be any faster than generating the doubles. Well if yes that it might be nice to use them instead, however I would much prefer to just get a random number representing number of booleans to change corresponding to the given percantage, so that if the percantage was 50% (illustrative as it would be rather 0.005% than 50%) I would get 5000 most often. Or some similar algorithm or function.

Comment: Marco: Yeah, the problem is, that this is not how the probability works, there is some chance that not one will be changed, as well as is there a chance all will  (ok, even ignoring these extreme and not exactly desirable cases, there should be some wariation in numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have set up a binomial model, with `n == count` and `p == rate`. The relevant number of values you should get, `x`, can be modeled as a normal model with center `n*p == count*rate` and standard deviation `sigma == Math.sqrt(p*(1-p)/n) == Math.sqrt(rate * (1-rate) / count)`.

You can easily calculate

```
int x = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(rate * (1-rate) / count)
        * r.nextGaussian() + count * rate)
```

Then you can generate `x` random numbers in the range using the following code.

```
Set<Integer> indices = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(indices.size() < x){
     indices.add(r.nextInt(count));
}
```

`indices` will now contain the correct indices, which you can use as you wish.

You'll only have to call `nextInt` a little more than `x` times, which should be much less than the `count` times you had to call it before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for the first part of code for a while.